# Docker container volumes are not working as expected

Tags: docker

Actually, I am trying to run the below following command

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/var/www/html --user node node:12.13.1-alpine ash.
```

#### Expected result

The files inside the container (i.e `/var/www/html` ) should have user as **node**.

#### Actual result

But, the files inside the containers are showing the same user as of the host.
Also, can't create a directory inside the container.

It is working for my other colleagues. So, any help in this would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,
Alwin

**Note:**

- Docker version 19.03.7, build 7141c199a2
- Have added necessary permission to docker command so that it doesn't
  need **sudo** for    running it

Answer (score 0):

Running docker run with --user does not change the permission of the original existing files. From Docker reference:

> The developer can set a default user to run the first process with the Dockerfile USER instruction. When starting a container, the operator can override the USER instruction by passing the -u option.

It only overrides the user running Node.js inside the container. During mount, the original permission and owner of `/var/www/html` is unchanged. Verify this by `ls -n` and see if the UID of the owner of the folder is the same when mounted inside Docker. Make sure the UID is the same as `node` user you specified.

I don't know how it works in your colleagues computers though. That's why it's important to use UID/GID instead just using username. The same username in the container can have different UID with the same username in the host.

EDIT: I checked that node image that you use contains `node` user with UID 1000. The first user created in Linux usually also has UID 1000. So if the `/var/www/html` is owned by UID 1000, it will run. But UID 1000 could possibly belong to different usernames in Docker and in the host. Because you specified `--user node`, which is translated into UID 1000 inside the container as username `node` itself exists, it won't work if `/var/www/html` is owned by different UID in your host, which probably is your case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add USER into Dockerfile before building

```
# App is running normal user mode
USER node
```

so now when you run docker image it will run with normal node user mode